# IntelliJ: scalac bad symbolic reference

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, apache-spark, sbt

In my build.sbt file I have this in my project.

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.10" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-graphx_2.10" % "1.3.1"   
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.3.1"
```

I just let it download all the libraries automatically. I'm adding graphx, the spark-core, and the scala sdk to one of my project modules but when I try to compile I'm getting:

> Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference. A signature in RDD.class refers to term hadoop
>   in package org.apache which is not available.
>   It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
>   the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling RDD.class.
>
> Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference. A signature in RDD.class refers to term io
>   in value org.apache.hadoop which is not available.
>   It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
>   the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling RDD.class.
>
> Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference. A signature in RDD.class refers to term compress
>   in value org.apache.io which is not available.
>   It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
>   the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling RDD.class.

The weird thing is if I download graphx/mllib directly from the maven repositories it seems to compile. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible source of error is the incorrect scalac version setting in the project. Right click project -> Open module settings -> Global Libraries, change/add the scala-sdk version appropriate to your project

Answer (score 0):

Please add the hadoop dependency. Something like

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" %% "hadoop-common" % "2.7.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" %% "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.7.1"
```

You may need to add other hadoop modules depending on your app.